# Unordered List CSS in Qards WP Plugin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using Qards plugin for WordPress. The plugin does not have an option to add bullet list in the visual editor. I have attempted to add UL/LI list but the list does not show up in preview.

I want to add UL list with standard circle. Once I have it visible in preview I will be able to style it with CSS Hero plugin. 
     [Link to reference page](http://atxspace.co/atx-space-2-4/)
     [Screen Shot of Visual Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsR9u.png)

```html
<section class="grid column-3 image-1 top-padding-10 bottom-padding-1 ">
  <div class="section-bg section-color" style="background-color: #ffffff; opacity: 1;"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 style=" font-family: 'Crete Round', serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-4  line-height-6 ">
      Seeking Creative, Passionate People.
    </h1>
    <p style=" text-align: center;  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-3  line-height-2 ">
      We think that great real estate can help create magic!
    </p>
    <p style=" text-align: center;  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-3  line-height-2 ">
      The synergy between people and architectural spaces
    </p>
    <p style=" text-align: center;  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-3  line-height-2 ">
      drives <font color="#707070">creativity</font> and leads to the establishment of stable,
    </p>
    <p style=" text-align: center;  font-family: 'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-3  line-height-2 ">
      profitable businesses
    </p>
    <ul class="grid-list">
      <li class="image-grid-item ">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://atxspace.co/wp-content/plugins/qards/../../uploads/2016/03/Arts___Entertainment_Photos_Product_Images___Interior_painted…___Creative_Market-1.png)"></div>
        <div class="description-holder">
          <div>
            <div>
              <h3 style=" color: rgb(66, 66, 66);  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-4  line-height-4 ">
                Bespoke Real Estate Service
              </h3>
              <ul style="list-style-type:circle">
                <li>Custom Market Research</li>
                <li>Needs Analysis</li>
                <li>Negotiation</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="image-grid-item ">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://atxspace.co/wp-content/plugins/qards/../../uploads/2016/03/Product_Mockups_Product_Images___320_Apple_Device…___Creative_Market.png)"></div>
        <div class="description-holder">
          <div>
            <div>
              <h3 style=" color: rgb(66, 66, 66);  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-4  line-height-4 ">
                Tech Tools
              </h3>
              <ul>
                <li>Tour Book App</li>
                <li>Online Deal Management</li>
                <li>Lease Analysis &amp; Comparison</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="image-grid-item ">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://atxspace.co/wp-content/plugins/qards/../../uploads/2016/03/spratx_work_35.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="description-holder">
          <div>
            <div>
              <h3 style=" color: rgb(66, 66, 66);  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-style: normal; " class=" font-size-4  line-height-4 ">
                Creative Scenarios
              </h3>
              <ul>
                <li>Shared Office Leasing</li>
                <li>Unique Spaces</li>
                <li>Multi-Use Facilities</li>
                <li>Integrated with PublicTransit</li>
                <li>Offset Your Annual Rent with SXSW &amp; Event Subleasing </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: http://atxspace.co/atx-space-2-4/

Comment: @Micheal Issac, Welcome to Stack Overflow community. Please format your question properly before posting, it's bit tough to understand it in the way you have mentioned it.

Comment: let me know if that is better. Sorry first post on here.